# Retrieve latest timestamp row from table using INNER JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, sql

want to retrieve the latest timestamp of the row of name from table. However only the table "location" has the timestamp.
I used INNER JOIN  to join the tables "elderly1" and "location" together. i am only able to show that i have retrieved the latest timestamp but not the latest "latitude" and "longitude" from the table "location". Please help.

### **Query**

```
SELECT e.name,e.illness, e.patient_id,e.patient_image,e.area, e.arduino_mac,
       l.arduino_mac, l.latitude, l.longitude,MAX(l.timestamp) as ts 
FROM elderly1 e 
JOIN location l 
    on e.arduino_mac = l.arduino_mac 
WHERE e.arduino_mac = l.arduino_mac 
GROUP BY e.name 
ORDER BY l.timestamp
```

Comment: Is this the query you're running? It's hard to read but looks like you should get 'cannot use e.patient_id, e.illness... in select list because it's not included in an aggregate function'

Comment: @artm - `MySQL` uses its [`GROUP BY` extensions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-extensions.html) by default.

Comment: You do not need to duplicate explicit `JOIN` with `WHERE` clause with the same condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to say much without knowing the candidate keys of each table, but in general you must make sure that the `SELECT` clause is functionally dependent of the `GROUP BY` clause. Given you formulation of the problem I would suggest something like:

```
SELECT e.name,e.illness, e.patient_id,e.patient_image,e.area, e.arduino_mac,
       l.arduino_mac, l.latitude, l.longitude, l.timestamp as ts 
FROM elderly1 e 
JOIN ( SELECT l1.arduino_mac, l1.latitude, l1.longitude, l1.timestamp
       FROM location l1
       WHERE timestamp = ( SELECT MAX(timestamp)
                           FROM LOCATION l2
                           WHERE l1.arduino_mac = l2.arduino_mac )
) as l
    on e.arduino_mac = l.arduino_mac 
ORDER BY l.timestamp
```

Comment: i have another question o ask.

Comment: i have another question o ask. @Lennart if i were to add another table, "zones" with values "id"(AI),"zone_name", and "password" for SESSION purposes and use "zone_name" from "zones" to tally with "zone_name" from elderly1 to only show patients in the particular zone with the particular SESSION. please help. thanks

Answer (score 1):

If the (arduino_mac,timestamp) tuple is unique in the location table, you could do something like this:

```
SELECT e.name
     , e.illness
     , e.patient_id
     , e.patient_image
     , e.area
     , e.arduino_mac
     , l.arduino_mac
     , l.latitude
     , l.longitude
     , l.timestamp
  FROM elderly1 e
  JOIN ( SELECT d.arduino_mac
              , MAX(d.timestamp) AS latest_ts
           FROM location d
          GROUP BU d.arduino_mac
       ) f
    ON f.arduino_mac = e.arduino_mac
  JOIN location l
    ON l.arduino_mac = f.arduino_mac
   AND l.timestamp   = f.lastest_ts
 GROUP BY e.name
 ORDER BY l.timestamp
```

The inline view `f` gets the "latest timestamp" for each value of arduino_mac. (Performance of the view query will be best if there's a suitable index available, e.g.

```
  ... ON location (arduino_mac,timestamp)
```

We can use that value of timestamp to retrieve the other columns on that row, with a join to the `location` table.

Note that if there are two (or more) rows with the same latest "timestamp" value for a given arduino_mac, then this query will retrieve all of the rows with that matching timestamp, and it will be indeterminate which of those rows will remain after the GROUP BY operation. (If we're guaranteed (arduino_mac,timestamp) is unique, this won't be an issue. In the more general case.)

In the same way, if there are multiple rows with the same `name` value in `elderly`, with different values of arduino_mac, it's indeterminate which of the matching `location` rows is retrieved, and returned.