# Multiple Table join and latest timestamp from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I'm trying to aggregate multiple fields into one query buy grabbing the latest clock/timestamp value for each item in the relevant history tables.
This is for a wall dashboard display and the built in functions are not enough to get a clean tidy output, but it does support sql queries.

Based on a previous question ([MySql Combine two queries (subselect or join or union)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57156247/mysql-combine-two-queries-subselect-or-join-or-union)) I have created the following, though it is functional the data is incorrect. I need to pull the last value from the clock column for each item.
There will be a third table to add once we have table partitioning in place, along with other items, this is just a minimal example to get going.

```
SELECT hosts.host,
max(case when items.name='DB2 CPU Usage' then history.value end) as ' DB2 CPU Usage',
max(case when items.name='DB2 Cache Hit Rate' then history.value end) as ' DB2 Cache Hit Rate',
max(case when items.name='DB2 Percent Rqst Waiting' then history.value end) as ' DB2 Percent Rqst Waiting',
max(case when items.name='DB2 Version' then history_text.value end) as ' DB2 Version'
from hosts
left join  items on items.hostid = hosts.hostid
left join  history on history.itemid = items.itemid
left join  history_text on history_text.itemid = items.itemid
where items.name like 'DB2%'
group by hosts.host, items.name, history.value
```

I have tried working off some examples such as these ([Join tables and return row with latest timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56996101/join-tables-and-return-row-with-latest-timestamp) and [Retrieve latest timestamp row from table using INNER JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26133655/retrieve-latest-timestamp-row-from-table-using-inner-join)) but am unable to make a functioning query using all the tables.

This works fine, but I cannot figure out how to combine
`select itemid,max(clock) as max_clock from history group by history.itemid order by max_clock desc limit 1`

Here is some sample data

```
hosts
+-----------+-------+
|host       |hostid |
+-----------+-------+
|server01   |10001  |
|server02   |10002  |
+-----------+-------+

items
+-------+-------+-------------------+
|itemid |hostid |name               |
+-------+-------+-------------------+
|9801   |10001  |DB2 CPU Usage      |
|9936   |10001  |DB2 Cache Hit Rate |
|9783   |10001  |DB2 Version        |
|9802   |10002  |DB2 CPU Usage      |
|9937   |10002  |DB2 Cache Hit Rate |
|9784   |10002  |DB2 Version        |
+-------+-------+-------------------+

history
+-------+-------+-----------+
|itemid |value  |clock      |
+-------+-------+-----------+
|9801   |86     |1565042153 |
|9801   |32     |1565042253 |
|9936   |12     |1565042120 |
|9936   |22     |1565042220 |
|9802   |41     |1565042153 |
|9802   |72     |1565042253 |
|9937   |99     |1565042120 |
|9937   |53     |1565042220 |
+-------+-------+-----------+

history_text
+-------+-------+-----------+
|itemid |value  |clock      |   
|9783   |9.7    |1565042120 |
|9783   |9.7    |1565042320 |
|9784   |10.5   |1565042123 |
|9784   |10.5   |1565042324 |
+-------+-------+-----------+
```

and a required output

```
+-----------+---------------+-------------------+---------------+
|           |DB2 CPU Usage  |DB2 Cache Hit Rate |DB2 Version    |
+-----------+---------------+-------------------+---------------+
|server01   |32             |22                 |9.7            |
|server02   |72             |53                 |10.5           |
+-----------+---------------+-------------------+---------------+
```

From each thing I have learned I have adapted to different queries already - thanks for your time it is much appreciated!

Comment: Note that `left join  items ... where items... like/equals` is the same as `inner join items`

Answer (score 0):

Your db design would be better for this  when you had two history tables one with the first value and the second with the second later value.
First this is the create version of your data, so that you can try it quickly with dbfidddle or sqlfiddle

```
CREATE TABLE hosts
  (`host` varchar(8), `hostid` int)
;

INSERT INTO hosts
  (`host`, `hostid`)
VALUES
  ('server01', 10001),
  ('server02', 10002)
;


CREATE TABLE items
 (`itemid` int, `hostid` int, `name` varchar(18))
;

INSERT INTO items
  (`itemid`, `hostid`, `name`)
VALUES
  (9801, 10001, 'DB2 CPU Usage'),
  (9936, 10001, 'DB2 Cache Hit Rate'),
  (9783, 10001, 'DB2 Version'),
  (9802, 10002, 'DB2 CPU Usage'),
  (9937, 10002, 'DB2 Cache Hit Rate'),
  (9784, 10002, 'DB2 Version')
;


CREATE TABLE history
  (`itemid` int, `value` DECIMAL(5,1) , `clock` int)
;

INSERT INTO history
  (`itemid`, `value`, `clock`)
VALUES
  (9801, 86, 1565042153),
  (9801, 32, 1565042253),
  (9936, 12, 1565042120),
  (9936, 22, 1565042220),
  (9802, 41, 1565042153),
  (9802, 72, 1565042253),
  (9937, 99, 1565042120),
  (9937, 53, 1565042220)
;


CREATE TABLE history_text
  (`itemid` int, `value` DECIMAL(5,1) , `clock` int)
;

INSERT INTO history_text
  (`itemid`, `value`, `clock`)
VALUES
  (9783, 9.7, 1565042120),
  (9783, 9.7, 1565042320),
  (9784, 10.5, 1565042123),
  (9784, 10.5, 1565042324)
;
```

And here is my solution to your problem

```
SELECT 
  host,
  MAX(IF(name = 'DB2 CPU Usage',value,NULL)) 'DB2 CPU Usage',
  MAX(IF(name = 'DB2 Cache Hit Rate',value,NULL)) 'DB2 Cache Hit Rate',
  MAX(IF(name = 'DB2 Version',value,NULL)) 'DB2 Version'
FROM
(
  SELECT i.itemid itemid, h.hostid hostid, name, value, h.host host FROM
   (
     SELECT MAX(value) value,h.itemid itemid FROM history h 
       INNER JOIN 
       (SELECT MAX(clock) clock,itemid FROM history 
       GROUP BY itemid
       ) hi 
      ON h.clock = hi.clock GROUP BY h.itemid
    UNION
    SELECT MAX(value) value,h.itemid itemid FROM history_text h 
      INNER JOIN 
      (SELECT MAX(clock) clock,itemid FROM history_text 
       GROUP BY itemid
      ) hi 
      ON h.clock = hi.clock GROUP BY h.itemid
   ) his 
   inner join items i on i.itemid =  his.itemid 
   inner join hosts h on h.hostid = i.hostid
) res GROUP BY host;
```

Result is

```
host    DB2 CPU Usage   DB2 Cache Hit Rate  DB2 Version
server01   32.0             22.0                9.7
server02   72.0             53.0               10.5
```

As you can see i started with history and history text. 
and i could not find a prettier Form for it.
It is not complicated you select first the maximum Date grouped by itemid and join it with the same table. than you have the right value for every itemid.
then I made the same  with history text.
Union that all, so we have all itemids that 
are needed.
The rest is inner joinig the rest of the tables.
And finally making the result